# Select only non-empty objects from array

Tags: json, filter, jq

I have a JSON array with objects as items. Some of the objects have properties, some don't. How can I filter the list with jq to keep only non-empty objects in the list?

Input:

```
[
  {},
  { "x": 42 },
  {},
  { "y": 21 },
  {},
  { "z": 13 }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  { "x": 42 },
  { "y": 21 },
  { "z": 13 }
]
```

I tried `jq 'select(. != {})'`, but the result still contains all items. Using `jq 'map(select(empty))'` doesn't keep any item and returns an empty array!

Comment: ```Object.keys(obj).length``` is one of the ways to check if an object contains any visible keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `map` to make `select` test individual objects:

```
jq 'map(select(. != {}))'
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` is required to apply the filter to every item in the array. Then `any` can be used: it will return `true` for objects with at least one property, and `false` if the object is empty.

```
$ jq -n '{} | any'
false
$ jq -n '{x:42} | any'
true
```

`empty` is not a test, but a generator for "no value" ([docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#empty)).

Solution:

```
map(select(any))
```

As noted by user [Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125671/philippe) in the comments, using `any` only works if the values of the objects' properties are not `false`. It would detect objects such as `{"x":false}` as "empty". A better approach is comparing the empty object directly or using `length`:

```
map(select(length>0))
```

Comment: `any` can't be used to test emptiness of object : `jq -n '{x:false} | any'` -> `false`

Comment: @Philippe oh, thanks! That's a detail which I missed

Comment: @knittl This happens will all falsy values, so you'd need to exclude `null` as well.

Comment: @pmf dropping `null` would be okay here (using the `length` approach. Comparing value with literal keeps nulls). Important is that `map` must be used and that `empty` is not a filter, but a generator.

Comment: @knittl I was of course talking about the `any` approach where dropping `{"x": null}` would in many cases not be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `del` filter:

```bash
jq 'del(.[] | select(length == 0))'
```

or

```bash
jq 'del(.[] | select(. == {}))'
```